# Get battery level with higher accuracy than 5%

Tags: iphone, battery

Our company is now developing an iPhone battery application.

I use the below code to get the battery level

```
UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
[myDevice setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
float batteryLevel = [myDevice batteryLevel];
```

However the accuracy of this API is 5%, for example 0% 5% 10% 15%.....20% 95% 100%

The requirements of my application demands 1% accuracy, for example 1% 2% 3%...99% 100%

Are there any ways to obtain this level of accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try interpolating between values, but it wouldn't be accurate.